# Passing FormCollection and FormData to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {
            var data = new FormData();
            var Form = $("#form2").serialize();
            var send = {FormData+&+ data};

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Product")',
                data: send,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        });
```

How to send FormData and Form object through ajax, please check the code its not working but it will tell you what I want to achieve 
And also please mention how to receive this in Controller.
Basically I want to send picture and formcollection to my controller

Thanks

Comment: this code will send your form data to your controller in a model , what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#btn2").click(function () {
            var data = new FormData($('.form').get(0));

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Product")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        });
```

Through googling I got this code but my controller still receiving null??

**Controller**

> public void AddProduct(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase myImage){}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form.serialize` to send data to your controller.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      var form = $('#form2');


        $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",
          url: form.attr( 'action' ),
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
          }
        } );


    } );
```

Comment: yes it will send the form elements except input file
I want to send form elements and input file to my controller, input file contains the picture

Comment: why are you not adding your data(picture)  in your form?

Comment: I have tried that but could not succeed

Comment: By your code I guess that you are trying to add a picture with picture data.If this is the case then you should recieve both in a form2 , there might be something missing in your html.plz update that

Comment: Also you can add your HttpPostedFileBase myImage in your product viewmodel and you will get everything in Product.Also have you tried passing only picture to controller just for testing

Comment: Thank you Sadaquat but now its giving me this error 

"the input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character"